# Dynamic In-App Settings

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, settings, inappsettingskit

I have an app where Location is important.  Currently I have a multi-value setting in the settings bundle where I have 5 locations defined.  The problem with this approach is that the settings bundle is static - i.e. I cannot update that from a JSON list on my server as far as I know.

I want to update the location list from a dynamic list on the server.

I have looked at InAppSettingsKit but this also uses the standard settings bundles.  Is it possible to use InAppSettingsKit to import settings updates dynamically from a remote list.

Are there other ways to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to change the list dynamically with regards to Settings.app. Settings.app always uses the static schema plist from your app bundle. (You could resort to a freeform text  field but that probably doesn't catch your case.)

With InAppSettingsKit, you can accomplish that but you have to do some extra work: For the dynamic parts, you'll want to use a [custom view controller](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit#custom-viewcontrollers), e.g. a table view controller.

Comment: So do you mean to remove the location multi-value field entirely from settings.app bundle and create it in a custom view controller using InAppSettingsKit?

Comment: Thanks.  It's a real pity that it's impossible to update settings.bundle with values from server.

Answer (score -1):

Best way for you handle this is storing the multi-values in the NSUserDefaults and start using them. In this method, you will be able to update the values as well as it will be persistent across multiple sessions.

**Edit (answers comment):**

Saving it to user defaults.

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"your Object", "Your Key"
                              nil];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Retriving it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Your Key"];
```

Comment: thanks for replying. Do you have an example of how this is done from data stored on a remote server?