# How to add dynamic TextField Group in iOS Settings Bundle Root.plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wish to add a Group of PSTextFieldSpecifiers as Apple's done within FaceTime's settings menu:

[image: FaceTime settings menu]

As seen under Group Titled "You can be reached by FaceTime at" - Is there any way to achieve this while staying under Apple's AppStore publish terms?
Making myself clearer - I wish to let users "Add another email...", and another, and so on...

Comment: No it's not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102431/dynamic-in-app-settings

Comment: @Fönsi unfortunately you may answer my question and I'll mark this as a proper solution. Thanks